# How to store " (double quote) char in a variable?

Tags: c++, char

I'm coding a c++ program but i have a problem in storing `"` char in a variable and after searching a solution in the web i discovred a way but whenever i compile it i get [Warning] \040 ..that's the arrays of chars i want to store :

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

me i did this :

```
const char com1[]="reg add \"\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Terminal Server\"\\ /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f";
```

the problem is that i get following output which puts a backslash after the ending " ..

```
reg add "\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server"\ /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

so can tell me pliz what to do ??

Comment: it has that because you told it to: ` \"\\ `. Fix your string and it will go away…

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
const char com1[]="reg add \"\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Terminal Server\"\\ /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f";
```

use

```
const char com1[]="reg add \"\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Terminal Server\" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f";
```

In your code there is an extra `\\`

Answer (score 0):

There's also a `\` that shouldn't be there after the `"` here - `"\HKEY`.

`\"\\` means an escaped `"` and an escaped `\`. You just want `\"` in both places.

```
const char com1[]="reg add \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Terminal Server\" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f";
```

Comment: According to the question, this is the string you want: `reg add "HKEY...`, not `reg add "\HKEY...`